# javascript: save table values to use as default

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Im trying to figure out how to add all the original values from a table to a variable/array or even to a similar table that could be use later to reset all values to original (when is loaded)

Table with the initial values is "**tabla**"

Then i have different functions to color the backgrounds depending on the ranges and the button pressed.
The thing is that when one of this buttons is press, then i need to reset the values to the original ones and i dont want to do it as function "**blank()**" because is a waste.

I tried doing it with a cycle but it never gets to the originals:

```html
var tabla2 = tabla;

for (var i = 0 ; i < 13; i++) {
 
            for (var j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
             
     tabla2.rows[i].cells[j].innerText =  tabla.rows[i].cells[j].innerText
    
    
            } 
    
    
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="language" content="english">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title>Table Highlighting</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 

 
$('#button2').click(function (){
    color='#F0FF00';
});
 
 
 $('#button3').click(function (){
  
     $('#tabla td').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'transparent');    
});
});
 
  
$('#button4').click(function (){
    color='#F0FF00';
});
 
 

 
 
 
</script>
<style>
table
{
 width: 520px;
 height: 520px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
table_botones
{
 width: 520px;
 height: 50px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
td
{
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 0px;
 border: 1px solid #666666;
 cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
 

 
</head>
<body>
<table id="tabla" width="520" border="0">
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">AA</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">AKs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">AQs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">AJs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">TAs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A9s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A8s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A7s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A6s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A5s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A4s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A3s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A2s</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">AKo</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">KK</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">
  KQs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">KJs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">KTs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K9s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K8s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K7s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K6s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K5s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K4s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K3s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K2s</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">AQo</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">KQo</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">QQ</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">QJs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">QTs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q9s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q8s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q7s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q6s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q5s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q4s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q3s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q2s</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">AJo</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">KJo</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">QJo</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">JJ</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">JTs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J9s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J8s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J7s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J6s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J5s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J4s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J3s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J2s</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">ATo</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">KTo</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">QTo</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">JTo</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">TT</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T9s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T8s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T7s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T6s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T5s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T4s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T3s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T2s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A9o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K9o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q9o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J9o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T9o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">99</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">98s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">97s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">96s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">95s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">94s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">93s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">92s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A8o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K8o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q8o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J8o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T8o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">98o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">88</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">87s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">86s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">85s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">84s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">83s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">82s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A7o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K7o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q7o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J7o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T7o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">97o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">87o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">77</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">76s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">75s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">74s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">73s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">72s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A6o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K6o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q6o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J6o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T6o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">96o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">86o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">76o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">66</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">65s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">64s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">63s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">62s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A5o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K5o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q5o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J5o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T5o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">95o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">85o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">75o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">65o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">55</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">54s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">53s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">52s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A4o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K4o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q4o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J4o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T4o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">94o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">84o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">74o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">64o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">54o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">44</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">43s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">42s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A3o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K3o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q3o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J3o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T3o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">93o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">83o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">73o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">63o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">53o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">43o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">33</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">32s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A2o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K2o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q2o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J2o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T2o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">92o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">82o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">72o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">62o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">52o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">42o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">32o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="button" onclick="raise('#33FF36')">Raise</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="raise('#F7F02E')">Call</button>
<button id="ep1" onclick="ep1()">UTG1</button>
<button id="ep2" onclick="ep2()">UTG2</button>
<button id="ep3">UTG3</button>
<button id="ep4">MP</button>
 

 
 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 
 
 
 function ep1()
 
 {
  
 blank();  
 $('#tabla td').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');    
}); 
  
 tabla.rows[0].cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[2].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";  
 tabla.rows[0].cells[4].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[5].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[10].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[11].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[2].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[2].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[3].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[6].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[6].innerText = "A8s:  5";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[7].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[7].innerText = "A7s:  7";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[8].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[8].innerText = "A6s: 14";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[9].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 //tabla.rows[0].cells[9].innerText = "A5s: 97";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[12].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[12].innerText = "A2s: 29";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[4].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[4].innerText = "KTs: 44"; 
 tabla.rows[2].cells[4].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[4].innerText = "TQs: 64";
 tabla.rows[3].cells[4].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[3].cells[4].innerText = "TJs: 65"; 
 tabla.rows[4].cells[4].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[4].cells[4].innerText = "TT: 64"; 
  
  colorear_rango();
  
 }
 
 
function ep2()
 
 {
 
 blank(); 
 
 $('#tabla td').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');    
}); 
  
 tabla.rows[0].cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[2].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";  
 tabla.rows[0].cells[4].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[5].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[10].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[10].innerText = "A4s:  68";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[11].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[11].innerText = "A3s:  65";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[2].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[2].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[3].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[6].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[6].innerText = "A8s:  66";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[7].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[7].innerText = "A7s:  31";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[8].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[8].innerText = "A6s: 17";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[9].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 //tabla.rows[0].cells[9].innerText = "A5s: 97";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[12].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[12].innerText = "A2s: 46";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[4].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[4].innerText = "KTs: 65"; 
 tabla.rows[2].cells[4].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[4].innerText = "TQs: 47";
 tabla.rows[3].cells[4].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[3].cells[4].innerText = "TJs: 64"; 
 tabla.rows[4].cells[4].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 //tabla.rows[4].cells[4].innerText = "TT: 64"; 
  
  colorear_rango();
  
 } 
 
 
 
function ep3()
 
 {
 
 blank(); 
  
 $('#tabla td').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');    
}); 
  
 tabla.rows[0].cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[2].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";  
 tabla.rows[0].cells[4].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[5].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[10].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[10].innerText = "A4s:  68";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[11].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[11].innerText = "A3s:  65";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[2].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[2].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[3].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[6].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[6].innerText = "A8s:  66";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[7].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[7].innerText = "A7s:  31";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[8].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[8].innerText = "A6s: 17";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[9].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 //tabla.rows[0].cells[9].innerText = "A5s: 97";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[12].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[12].innerText = "A2s: 46";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[4].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[4].innerText = "KTs: 65"; 
 tabla.rows[2].cells[4].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[4].innerText = "TQs: 47";
 tabla.rows[3].cells[4].style.backgroundColor = "#AFEFE8";
 tabla.rows[3].cells[4].innerText = "TJs: 64"; 
 tabla.rows[4].cells[4].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 //tabla.rows[4].cells[4].innerText = "TT: 64"; 
  
  colorear_rango();
  
 }
 
 
 
 
function colorear_rango(){
 
   for (var i = 0 ; i < 13; i++) {
 
            for (var j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
    
    if(tabla.rows[i].cells[j].style.backgroundColor==='rgb(255, 255, 255)')
             
     tabla.rows[i].cells[j].style.color='rgb(255, 255, 255)';
    
    
            } 
    
    
        }
 
 
 }
  
function raise(color){
 
 //color='#000';
   $('td').toggle( function() {
    $(this).css('background', color);
  },function(){
  $(this).css('background', 'transparent');
   
  });
 
}

function blank(){
 
 tabla.rows[0].cells[0].innerText = "AA";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[1].innerText = "AKs";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[2].innerText = "AQs";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[3].innerText = "AJs";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[4].innerText = "ATs";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[5].innerText = "A9s";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[6].innerText = "A8s";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[7].innerText = "A7s";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[8].innerText = "A6s";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[9].innerText = "A5s";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[10].innerText = "A4s";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[11].innerText = "A3s";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[12].innerText = "A2s";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[1].innerText = "KK";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[2].innerText = "KQs";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[3].innerText = "KJs";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[4].innerText = "KTs";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[5].innerText = "K9s";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[6].innerText = "K8s";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[7].innerText = "K7s";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[8].innerText = "K6s";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[9].innerText = "K5s";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[10].innerText = "K4s";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[11].innerText = "K3s";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[12].innerText = "K2s";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[2].innerText = "QQ";
 tabla.rows[3].cells[3].innerText = "JJ";
 tabla.rows[4].cells[4].innerText = "TT";
 tabla.rows[5].cells[5].innerText = "99";
 tabla.rows[6].cells[6].innerText = "88";
 tabla.rows[7].cells[7].innerText = "77";
 tabla.rows[8].cells[8].innerText = "66";
}
 
 
 
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using

```
var tabla2 = tabla;
```

`tabla2` references the same *entity* as `tabla`. So, if you make any mods to `tabla` you also make mods to `tabla2` and vice-versa.

To create a new entity and keep it for future reference, you could do any of the following, depending on what `tabla` is:

**Use JSON** (works for objects and arrays).
Hackish, but works, unless you're trying to clone an object containing cyclic references, which results in an error:

```
let tabla2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tabla));
```

**Use object specific methods** (for objects only)

```
let tabla2 = () => tabla;
// or 
let tabla2 = Object.assign({}, tabla);
```

**Use array specific metods** (for arrays only)

```
let tabla2 = tabla.slice(0);
// or
let tabla2 = tabla.concat([])
// or
let tabla2 = Array.from(tabla)
// or 
let tabla2 = [...tabla];
```

**Note:** various JavaScript utility libraries and frameworks offer cloning under various names:

- lodash and underscore have `_.clone()` and `_.deepClone()`
- AngularJS has `.copy()`
- jQuery has `.clone()`.
- ... the list is much longer, including specific npm packages dedicated to shallow or deep cloning.